# How to merge Js objects with same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

We need to go over from each input key and check with others if they have some value in common. If they, have we need to concat them together and also display the pairs. If there is nothing in common, then display an empty array and provide output as given.

```
input : 
{
    "harsh" : ["cricket", "vollyball"],
    "aasim" : ["cricket", "football", "ludo", "COD", "rugb", "vollyball", "Racing"],
    "jignesh" : ["cycling", "cricket"],
    "jimish" : ["cycling"],
    "prince" : ["vollyball","football"],
    "raj" : ["ludo","cricket","cycling"]
}

output : 

{
    "harsh, aasim":["cricket","vollyball"],
    "harsh, jignesh":["cricket"],
    "harsh, jimish":[],
    "harsh, prince":["vollyball"],
    "harsh, raj":["cricket"],
    "aasim, jignesh": ["cricket"],
    "aasim, jimish": [],
    "aasim, prince": ["vollyball","football"],
    "aasim, raj": ["ludo","cricket"],
    "jignesh, jimish" : ["cycling"],
    "jignesh, prince" : [],
    "jignesh, raj" :["cycling"],
    "prince, raj" : []
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
const findDuplicates = arr => arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) !== index);
    
const rearangeObject = providedObj => {
     const newObj = {};
     const keys = Object.keys(providedObj);
    
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          for (let j = i + 1; j < keys.length; j++) {
              let str = keys[i] + ", " + keys[j];
              newObj[str] = findDuplicates([...providedObj[keys[i]], ...providedObj[keys[j]]]);
          }
      }
      return newObj;
}
    
const providedObj = {
      "harsh": ["cricket", "vollyball"],
      "aasim": ["cricket", "football", "ludo", "COD", "rugb", "vollyball", "Racing"],
      "jignesh": ["cycling", "cricket"],
      "jimish": ["cycling"],
      "prince": ["vollyball", "football"],
      "raj": ["ludo", "cricket", "cycling"]
};
console.log(rearangeObject(providedObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
it's easily achievable in PHP but if this code work for you that's fine

```
  var name = [
        "harsh",
        "aasim",
        "jignesh",
        "jimish",
        "prince",
        "raj"
    ]
    var array1 = [
        ["cricket", "vollyball"],
        ["cricket", "football", "ludo", "COD", "rugb", "vollyball", "Racing"],
        ["cycling", "cricket"],
        ["cycling"],
        ["vollyball", "football"],
        ["ludo", "cricket", "cycling"]
    ];
    //array1= console.log(array1);
    array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

        for (var k = 1; k < array1.length; k++) {
            var array5 = array1[i].filter(function(obj) {
                return array1[k].indexOf(obj) == -1;
            });
            
            if(array5.length!=0){
            array[name[i]] = array5
            
            }

        }
    }

    console.log(array);
```

Comment: Getting empty array for both array and array5

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = {
    "harsh" : ["cricket", "vollyball"],
    "aasim" : ["cricket", "football", "ludo", "COD", "rugb", "vollyball", "Racing"],
    "jignesh" : ["cycling", "cricket"],
    "jimish" : ["cycling"],
    "prince" : ["vollyball","football"],
    "raj" : ["ludo","cricket","cycling"]
};

const inputKeys = Object.keys(input);
const keyCombinations = [];
while (inputKeys.length) {
  const k0 = inputKeys.shift();
  inputKeys.forEach(k1 => keyCombinations.push([k0, k1]));
}
const output = {};
keyCombinations.forEach(k => output[k.join(', ')] = input[k[0]].filter(k0 => input[k[1]].includes(k0)));
console.log(output);
```